# Registering application for receiving particular file type

Tags: android, xamarin, android-intent

**EDIT:** After comment that the code should be right I was playing with things a little and I found that:

When I try to open pgn file from file browser, my application is in the list. I didn't try this previously as my primary goal was to catch file **shared** by another application. Didn't know it is different. I will try to find improvement tomorrow, any ideas welcome...

---

***Original question, not so important any more***

I want my application to be one of possible applications to open Intent with concrete mime type. I'm pretty sure there must be this topic covered somewhere, but no matter what I tried, my application was still invisible (and it was invisible also for other mime types). This is part of code in application manifest of another application on github that works.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/x-chess-pgn" />
</intent-filter>
```

This is one of tries I made

```
[Activity(MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen",LaunchMode =Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
[IntentFilter(actions: new[] { "android.intent.action.VIEW" },DataMimeTypes = new[] {"application/x-chess-pgn"}, Categories = new [] {Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault} )]
public class StartPageActivity : Activity
{
...
}
```

And this is another one

```
protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ActionView, "application/x-chess-pgn");
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = new PgnBroadcast();
    RegisterReceiver(receiver, filter);
    ...
}
```

I was also trying doing the same in manifest file, but it's not much in my taste and it didn't work either. Is some additional action required to my application being visible by system for concrete intent type? Video or link would be greately appreciated.

Comment: Assuming your device has `application/x-chess-pgn` in its WebKit.MimeTypeMap database, your attribute based `[IntentFilter(...` should work fine , assuming you are trying to open a `.pgn` file which is the registered file extension :`MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetExtensionFromMimeType("application/x-chess-pgn")`

Comment: @SushiHangover After your comment I narrowed the search and found better description of the problem. What I was asking really worked, I only wanted and tested slightly different functionality. Edited question, will continue tomorrow with searching. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with system properties of android I was digging in wrong place. All the time I was testing recieving file via **share** action. To be able to catch this, there must be

> "android.intent.action.SEND"

action in intent filter. Now my application is visible as opener both from file browser and via sharing.

```
[IntentFilter(actions: new[] { "android.intent.action.VIEW", "android.intent.action.SEND" },DataMimeTypes = new[] { "application/x-chess-pgn" }, Categories = new [] {Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault} )]
```